# Accessor does not have implementation?

Tags: c#, testing, compiler-errors, mstest, accessor

I get the following error:

> Error 1   Method 'DoFoo' in type
>   'MyNamespace.GenericFooClass_Accessor`1'
>   from assembly 'MyLibrary,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an
>   implementation.   Testing.MyLibrary

I have no idea what it's talking about considering the method is implemented... it isn't abstract.

```
public abstract class GenericFooClass<T> : IGenericFoo<T>
{
    public virtual void DoFoo() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Where does `GenericFooClass_Accessor` come from? You are defining only `GenericFooClass`, without any `Accessor`. Does it come from some framework?

Comment: Post more code please: `IGenericFoo<T>`

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/415357/unit-test-project-fails-to-build-because-of-accessor-generic-interface-derivation#details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessors are going to be deprecated and have a lot of bugs in them. The language updates require more resources to update the accessors code-generation than they will give, hence a lot of bugs.

**Further Reading**:

[Generation of Private Accessors (Publicize) and Code Generation for Visual Studio 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vstsqualitytools/generation-of-private-accessors-publicize-and-code-generation-for-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Interesting find. My teacher used private accessors, and approximately 40% of students had severe issues with it not working as expected, even though they used them in the exact same way. This would pretty much explain it. It also seems that they are removed entirely in Visual Studio 11 beta.